# conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value: ONLY for leap year day

Tags: sql-server, datetime, leap-year

I am trying to insert date into a datetime column after formatting getdate() tovarchar(8) using convert function. I see it works for most part but incidentally when date is leap date(29th feb) it fails with conversion of varchar to datetime error.

I changed varchar(8) to varchar(9) which finally solved the problem. Any idea if 29th Feb is stored different in SQL server?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[temp_insert]
(
[TimeStamp] [datetime] NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

insert into temp_insert values(convert(varchar(8),(getdate()+1),113))--*inserts 1st march 2020*

GO

insert into temp_insert values(convert(varchar(8),(getdate()),113))--*fails with conversion error*

GO

insert into temp_insert values(convert(varchar(9),(getdate()),113))--*giving 9 bytes in varchar, inserts 29th Feb without issues.*


GO

select * from temp_insert--*shows 2 rows including 29th feb leap day*

GO
```

Comment: Why are you converting `GETDATE()` to a `varchar` at all when you're inserting into a `datetime` column. Even if you are why the format `dd mon yyyy hh:mi:ss:mmm` and not the ISO format `yyyyMMdd`? `GETDATE()` returns a `datetime` data type, so what's wrong with it?

Comment: If you run `SELECT convert(varchar(8),(getdate()),113)` you'll see the problem as well. What "date" is `'29 Feb 2'` meant to represent?

Comment: @larnu: Thank you for the kind attention. I am not saying what i posted is the right way to code but all i was looking to understand is why 29th Feb requires an extra byte to be inserted in the datetime column. I just stumbled upon this while working with one of my dev guys who asked help on this. If you run the snippet i have posted, you will see it works only for 1st and last insert, not the middle one.

Comment: You have your explanation. In short - read the documentation (for convert), know the style used, count characters correctly, and NEVER use 2 digit years. More importantly, learn to debug your own code. There is much that can be improved here beyond just making the code "work".

Answer (score 2):

If you take the `INSERT` that fails on it own, and break it into parts, it becomes very obvious what the problem is.

It fails because `convert(varchar(8),(getdate()),113)` returns the `varchar` `'29 Feb 2'`. If you take the value `'28 Feb 2'` and convert it to a `datetime` you get the value `2002-02-28 00:00:00.000`; ergo `'29 Feb 2'` would be 29 February 2002. 2002 was not a leap year, so the conversion fails.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way to do it. Your table already has a datetime field, so no need to use `convert` on the values like getdate(), since they are already of **datetime** type.

Just **store** the values as datetime, then use the [`FORMAT` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to **render** the date/times the way you want.

Use the [DATEADD function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) instead eg `DATEADD(day, 1, getdate())`. And be aware that using [reserved keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) (here: `TIMESTAMP`) is something to avoid.